# Varchar2 in oracle update query from SSIS project

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I need to make an update to in Oracle's database using SSIS. I am using the custom database task and using a query like:

```
  UPDATE Table SET column1 = ? where KEY = ?
```

The key is taken from SQL Server table and is a type of nvarchar(3), the key in oracle database is of type varchar2(3). First it was complaining that the key is 4 character so I change the query to

```
  UPDATE Table SET column1 = ? where KEY = TRIM(CAST(? AS VARCHAR(3)))
```

It is working for keys which has the 3 characters, but there are also the 2 characters long one. I've tried trim it, convert it. But I cannot make it work for 2 characters keys.

Oracle chararcter set for char is AL32UTF8 and for NCHAR - AL16UTF16.

Comment: are you sure one of the systems doesn't pad with a space or something?  those that look to be 2 if you select where key = '12' in both databases directly, do you get results both times?  what about if you do a length on those that appear to be 2 do you get lengths of 3?

Comment: The query run directly in oracle makes the update. So the keys in oracle has no spaces. The same for the source in SQL Server, I've check the length and it is 2 characters long just before the update step. I've also tried  KEY=TRIM(CAST(? AS VARCHAR(3))), but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Is it possible that characters comming from SQL Server take up multiple bytes in Oracle and thus don't fit? For example if the Oracle DB has the characterset set to AL32UTF8, then each char can take one to four bytes, with 7-bit ASCII characters taking a single byte, everything else taking more. By default `varchar2(3)` is `varchar(3 byte)` not `varchar(3 char)`. Each character on SQL Server's nvarchar is as 16 bit UNICODE character or half of a surrogate pair. If SQL Server had two non ascii chars it could become 4 (or more) bytes on Oracle, in this situation.

Comment: All of the keys use only ASCI codes. There is an issue that DT_WSTR which SSIS represents MS SQL varchars and should oracle's varchar2 is 2 bytes longer than it really are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem by creating the derived column with KEY_LEN as LEN(key) before the update step. Then I've used it in update as the third param:

```
UPDATE Table SET column1 = ? where KEY = SUBSTR(?,0,?)
```